# SQL JOIN returns more records than expected

Tags: sql, join

I have the table:

```
Country city population
------------------------
Israel  RG  100
Israel  TA  300
US  NY  900
US  SF  700
```

In order to get for each country the max population I am running the below query:

```
select Country, max(population) as maxPopulation 
from A 
group by Country
```

I want to get full output:

```
Country city population
-----------------------
Israel  TA  300
US  NY  900
```

In order to do it I need to join on the full table - please correct me if I am wrong.

```
select A.Country, A.city, A.population 
from A 
right join
     (select Country,  max(population) as maxPopulation 
      from A 
      group by Country) temp on temp.Country = A.Country
```

This returns all the 4 records... instead of 2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use correlated *subquery* :

```
select a.*
from a 
where population = (select max(a1.population) from a a1 where a1.Country = a.Country);
```

For your `JOIN` query version, you need one more condition that is `. . . and temp.maxPopulation = A.Population` & why you need right join here only `inner join` is sufficient :

```
select a.*
from a inner join
       (select Country,  max(population) as maxPopulation 
        from a 
        group by Country
       ) temp 
       on temp.Country = a.Country and temp.maxPopulation = a.population;
```

Comment: This only works if the population is unique inside a given country, think you somehow need to include the city as well

Answer (score 0):

I would use a standard CTE:

```
with
x as (
  select country, max(population) as pop from A group by country
)
select A.*
from A
join x on x.country = A.country and x.pop = A.population
```

A [desirable?] side effect of this query, is that if there are multiple cities with the same max population it will show them all.